# Adsense Vignette ads applying to form submit button

Tags: html, forms, adsense

I've noticed that google adsense vignette ads are performing well on my site, but they do not appear when the primary function is performed- notably the clicking of a form submit button.

I can't find any reference in google's documentation about what specific links the ads will attach to, but using the debugger it seems to work on hard links on the page, which includes links on images.

Is there any known way to make these work on form submit buttons, or a good workaround that will enable them- such as using an href link that then submits the form via script?

Comment: Hi Brad, did you manage to figure this out? Thanks

Comment: I need to look at it again, but I made some change where the submit button was replaced with a normal button with an href... if I recall. and it uses javascript to submit the form now.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like an interesting solution.

Comment: I'm re-checking it now, and it seems to pop the interstitial but then continue to post the form (and the ad disappears), so it's definitely not working correctly now. I know it did before so I'm not sure what changed. So- still looking for a solution.